# End of menu is closing program

Tags: c, function, menu, linked-list

I've currently got a working linked list within a function, my program begins by calling a menu (switch statement in a function) in `main`, which then gives you the option to:

- Add data into the linked list.
- Save the data to a text file.
- Display the data.

I'm having trouble working out how to call the menu back up to my program once the functions come to an end. Currently once I have added some data into my linked list the program ends. How do I make the program call the menu again instead of terminating?

```
main() 
{
    Menu();
}

void AddPacket()
{
   //Linked list inside here
}

void Menu()
{ 
    //Menu creation
}
```

I tried not to add loads of code because for the last two questions I've asked other people have just completed the code for me and I want to try to work this one out myself.

Comment: Perhaps a `while()` loop in `main()` on a return value from `Menu()` that says do, or do NOT continue? Just a thought.

Comment: Cheers for the answer! yes that would make sence i'll begin working on it

Answer (score 2):

You should have the call to `Menu()` inside a loop.  That way, when your `AddPacket` returns, it will go through another iteration.  I am assuming that you call `AddPacket()` from within `Menu()`.

Comment: main() {

    do{

    Menu();

    } while(menu<4);


}

This was the solution i came up with (option 4 was exit programme)